# Does CUDA 11.2 supports backward compatibility with application that is compiled on CUDA 10.2?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have the base image for my application built with nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04.I have to run that application in the cluster which is having cuda version

NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03 Driver Version: 460.32.03 CUDA Version: 11.2.

My application is not giving me right prediction results for the GPU trained model(it is returning the base score as prediction output).However, it is able to return accurate prediction results for the CPU-trained model.so, I am speculating it as the CUDA version incompatibility issue between the two. I want to know that whether CUDA version 11.2 works well with application that is complied with CUDA 10.2 or not..

Comment: What the cluster nvidia-smi is showing you isn't a CUDA version. It is the maximum version of the CUDA APIs which the driver supports.

Comment: ohh, I see...Is it occuring due to CUDA env incompatibility? any lead to get to the bottom of the issue?Thanks in Advance

Comment: Very unlikely. Typically a program would fail with missing libraries if there was a problem with version mismatches. Otherwise it should just work. Drivers are naturally backwards compatible. This sounds like something you should talk to your cluster administrators about

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible for an application compiled with CUDA 10.2 to run in an environment that has CUDA 11.2 installed. This is part of [the CUDA compatibility model/system](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/).

Otherwise, there isn't enough information in this question to diagnose why your application is behaving the way you describe.  For that, SO [expects](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).